# Is SOLR loading the right schema.xml properties?

Tags: solr

So here is the description of one of the fields in my schema.xml :

```
<field name="ContactEmail" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" omitNorms="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" omitPositions="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false"/>
```

As you can see UI have set indexed, omitNorms, omitTermFreqAndPositions as False and omitPositions as true.

But when I look in the UI on my browser for the schema I see the following :

[image]

So no matter what I set to true or false the green check sign is always there.

Does that mean this field is indexed, or the Omit Norms not omitted?

Comment: Did you reload the core after updating the schema?

Comment: @YoungHobbit yes I placed the new file, and restarted **SOLR** but the schema stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field definition looks ok. And it shows up in UI. So it is not a spelling error or some such. I would check for:

1. Duplicate field definition. Maybe there are two and the other one overrides the one you are trying to modify
2. Check you are looking at the right schema. Assuming Solr 4+, in the collection's overview screen in the Admin UI, it tells you the instance directory. Is your schema file somewhere under that?
3. If you are using SolrCloud, you need to upload the changed definition to ZooKeeper. After the initial upload, the file is not used. Your Admin UI will tell you if you are running a cloud, if you are not sure.

I would also create a new field and see if that shows up. If it does not, you have a wrong file for whatever reason. If it does, you more likely to have a duplicate definition or spelling error or some such.